# Excel - Cut Rows Programmatically

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel worksheet that has 30k+ rows.  I'd like to cut the first 14k rows, but manually doing it (highlighting selected columns with mouse) seems like an insane waste of time.

How can I do this pro grammatically?  I don't actually have scripting experience in Excel, but I can program in `PHP`.  I'm sure I could use the `PHPExcel` module at `PEAR` to create a script that can copy the first 14k rows and insert it into a new spreadsheet object, but that seems a lot more complicated for what I need.

Another option would be to save the Excel file as a csv file and import into a mysql database table.  The problem with this is that the reason I need to cut the first 14k rows is that those columns aren't correctly aligned (whereas the remainder are), which makes a db import a problem.

Comment: Wow, that worked perfectly.  Thanks!  You should offer that as an answer so that I can select it as the answer and close the thread (plus you'll get some rep).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you insist on doing it programmatically, the syntax is:
`range("1:14000").cut`

Otherwise, selecting manually IS quicker, if you know how to do it:
press ctrl+G (short for Edit, Go to) then type 1:14000, then press Enter. Done.
With MS-Office, the first rule has always been: the best program is no program.

Comment: Note you can also do this  `Range("1:14000").Cut Sheet2.Range("A1")`